# DynamoDB: Coordinating AWS Console access with client access (where are my tables?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In the AWS console, I can create a table in a given region, say Northern California.  When I try to access that region from the client (I'm using the Faraday library written for clojure, but it probably doesn't matter), it can't find the resource.  When I created the table from the client, I don't see it in Northern California:   so I looked around and found it in Northern Virginia.  All my reads and writes are fine, they just happen to go to Northern Virginia.

Now, I don't really care what region the tables are stored in, but does this mean that I always have to create my tables from the client to ensure that the writes are going to the correct place?  Is there some way to set the defaults so that the region in which my data is stored is always in the same place, or will the database always know where to look based on my credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb is available in many regions and each region has its own endpoint. I think you can configure your clojure dynamodb client to use a proper endpoint based on the region. In your case I guess North Virginia is the default endpoint/region that your client uses.

for example in my java code I am doing something like this to initialize my client:

```
dynamo = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
dynamo.setRegion(usWest2);
```

You can search for region or endpoint in your clojure code and configure it.